# I'm trying to add textboxes within ordered list onclick of a button using JavaScript and also increment ID name while adding the textbox

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-metro

I tried using document.createElement, which works fine to add textbox but I can't increment ID name.
I am using it in a metro app.

Comment: Have you tried using a For loop to increment? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: How are you providing the "ID name" to createElement?

Comment: I am using createElement to add Textbox

Comment: function addInput () {
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
input.id = "ID name";
document.getElementById("list").appendChild(input);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form>
  No. of lines:
  <input type="text" id="number" value="0"/>
  <br/>
  <input type="button" id="button" value="Add Line" />
</form>
<div>
  <ol id="linedata">
  </ol>
</div>
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", incrementValue);
function incrementValue() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('number').value = value;
  var list = document.createElement('li');
  var box = document.createElement('input');
  box.type = 'text';
  box.id = 'line' + value;
  box.placeholder='Line ' + value;
  list.appendChild(box);
  document.getElementById("linedata").appendChild(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function textBox(noOfInputTag){

     noOfInputTag = noOfInputTag*1; // Convert to Number
       //noOfInputTag is used to get total textbox you want to create                                
    for(var i = 0; i <= noOfInputTag; i++){
        var textbox = document.createElement('input');
        textbox.type = 'text';`enter code here`
        textbox.id = 'textBox_' + i; // As number of textbox increases id get incremented 
        document.body.appendChild(textbox); 
    }
}
textBox(2);
```

Comment: Please add a description explaining what you did

Comment: function addInput () { 
    for(var i = 0; i <= 50; i++){
    var input = document.createElement("input"); 
    input.type = "text"; 
    input.id = "name"+i; 
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(input); 
    }
    }

Comment: When I execute ID name is generated as name50 for instances.

Comment: How would you want to generate it?

Comment: For every instance I need the ID name to be incremented like name1, name2, name3,...., name50.

Comment: Please find below code
Call function on button click
var x=1

function addTextBox()
{
   var d = document.getElementById('div');
   d.innerHTML += "<input type='text' id='tst"+ x++ +"'><br >";
}

Comment: Where I should place var x=1

Comment: I got everything working expect the ID name increment.

Comment: When I use function textbox I get error ' unable to get property 'appendChild' of undefined of n null reference.

Comment: Can you explain it to me in detail?

Comment: I used this function.    function addline(n){
     n = n*1;
    for(var i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        var box = document.createElement('input');
        box.type = 'text';
        box.id = 'line' + i;
        document.getElementbyId("linedata").appendChild(box); 
    }
}
addline(2);

Comment: var line=document.getElementById("add");
line.addEventListener("click", addline, false); and this for button click.

Comment: function addline(n){
  n = n*1; 
  for(var i = 0; i <= n; i++){ 
  var box = document.createElement('input'); 
  box.type = 'text'; box.id = 'line' + i; 
  document.getElementById("linedata").appendChild(box); 
  }
} 

var line=document.getElementById("add");

line.addEventListener("click", function(){
  addline(2);
}, false);

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kyq4d3xg/ Check this, it adds three textboxes on every click.

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: When I add a new textbox the content of all the textboxes resets.